# AS3: TextFormatAlign not doing anything

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got a TextField that I am trying to use alignment with, and it is not doing anything.  Trace says the container is 300 wide and the TextField is 100 wide.  Everything is imported and there are no errors.  Here is the a test class to demonstrate the behavior:

```
public class TextFieldAligning extends Sprite
{
    private var textField:TextField;
    public function TextFieldAligning()
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        this.textField = new TextField();
        this.textField.text = "text";
        addChild(this.textField);

        this.width = 300;
        this.textField.width = 100;

        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.align = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;
        this.textField.defaultTextFormat = format;
    }
}
```

With or without those last 3 lines in the constructor, the formatting lines, the TextField behaves exactly the same.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Once the textfield already has some text assigned, you need to use `this.textField.setTextFormat(format);` as well. The defaultTextFormat() applies only to newly inserted text (=text that you input after you call the defaultTextFormat setter).